# How to check multiple permission condition in if statement using laravel spatie package?

Tags: if-statement, laravel-5, laravel-permission

I need to check condition in if statement for multiple permissions. It is using spatie package from laravel. I use this code below but it seems doesn't work. It can display the output but the output is not correct. It doesn't filter the condition.

```
if (auth()->user()->can('View Consultant') || auth()->user()('View Administration') 
|| auth()->user()('View Accountant') || auth()->user()('All departments')) 
 {

        $itemregistrations = DB::table('itemregistrations')
                             ->where('categoryid','=', '1',',','2',',','3')
                             ->get();

        return view('profil.index', compact('itemregistrations'));

 }
```

Is the code is correct?

The condition is the users with permission (view consultant, view administration, view accountant, all departments) can view list of consultant, administration and accountant from all departments.

For users with permission(view consultant only) can only view consultant list.

Answer (score 7):

`@can` blade directive accepts an array of permissions, the result is the same as `->hasAllPermissions`

```
@can(['user create', 'user edit'])
    ...
@endcan
```

Also there's another blade directive called `@canany`, the result is the same as `->hasAnyPermission`

```
@canany(['user create', 'user edit'])
    ...
@endcanany
```

Tested on these versions:

```
laravel/framework 8.83.5
spatie/laravel-permission 3.18.0
```

Comment: thanks, @canany(['user create', 'user edit']) its works for me on laravel 9.42.2

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation,

> You can check if a user has Any of an array of permissions:

```
$user->hasAnyPermission(['edit articles', 'publish articles', 'unpublish articles']);
```

So, you can do the following to check for multiple condition.

```
if (auth()->user()->hasAnyPermission(['View Consultant', 'View Administration', 'View Accountant', 'All departments']) 
 {
        $itemregistrations = DB::table('itemregistrations')
                             ->where('categoryid','=', '1',',','2',',','3')
                             ->get();

        return view('profil.index', compact('itemregistrations'));

 }
```

Comment: i am using (Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('View Consultant')) can solve the problem with if statement..thanks for your reply..

Comment: Yeah that works too. I was answering according to your question code.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check that the model has all the permissions, you should use method `hasAllPermissions()`. For example:

```php
if (\Auth::user()->hasAllPermissions('View Consultant', 'View Administration', 'View Accountant', 'All departments')) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be used in 2 ways.
Single control is as follows.

```
@can('edit articles')
  //
@endcan
```

Multiple control is as follows.

```
@if(auth()->user()->can('edit articles') && auth()->user()->can('edit uploads'))
  //
@endif
```